# Vim syntax javaid.vim dotfile didn't work

Tags: java, vim, syntax, highlight

Recently I use Vim to write java program. However, the bad thing is that vim default java syntax is not satisfying.

I checked the help doc, type `:help java.vim`, and found this one http://www.fleiner.com/vim/syntax/javaid.vim. This dotfile can highlight most java standard classes. And it almost saved my day.

Then I followed the guide carefully, yet surprisingly got the error message
like this:

```
Error detected while processing /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/javaid.vim

E492: Not an editor command:   JavaHiLink javaR_Java javaR_ 
E492: Not an editor command:   JavaHiLink javaC_JavaApplet javaC_Java  
E492: Not an editor command:   JavaHiLink javaR_JavaAwt javaR_Java 
E492: Not an editor command:   JavaHiLink javaR_JavaAwtColor javaR_JavaAwt
```

And lot of similar error messages. I have read the doc and found the update day is 2005, so is something too old to compile correctly?

So, kind Stack Overflowers, can offer better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For compatibility with very old Vim versions, old syntax scripts defined a custom `{filetype}HiLink` command. I guess the `javaid.vim` syntax was written to reuse that definition from `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/java.vim`, but that script has been cleaned up (some time ago).

As the syntax script seems to be unmaintained, I'd simply replace `JavaHiLink` with `hi def link`. This should fix the errors, and work in all Vim versions you'd encounter today.